# Writing a dax query for a particular machine for multiplying it with a constant

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to do something like this : 
IF ( table_name[Machine_name] == 'A' , then multiply it with a constant (eg:40) , else just break the statement)
I have worked in Python before and using that logic , can something similar be done using DAX?

Data is sort of like this :

```
Machine_Name | Constant 
A | 20
B | 50
C | 30
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't multiply text ("A") with a number. What do you want to be multiplied?

Answer (score -1):

Without more information its difficult to say exactley what you should do, but you can use both IF and SWITCH i DAX:

[IF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/if-function-dax)

[SWITCH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/switch-function-dax)